# Wiped my version 1 IPad and it won't load Facebook now

Tags: ipad

Facebook says it needs IOS version 7 to run, I had Facebook on it before I wiped it. Can I get an older version of Facebook back?

Answer (score 1):

iOS will let you download the last compatible version if you already have the app in your purchase history.

You can add the app to your purchase history using iTunes on your computer, since iTunes is version-agnostic. Once you've downloaded the app on iTunes, it will be in your purchase history and attempting to download it again on your device should prompt you to accept an older version of the app.

Comment: I wiped it to give it away to give it to someone. I tried setting it up for them, it's Facebook that I tried to load and it needs version 7 i think was the message.